# program will not go to else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

This program is supposed to print an error if you enter too many seats. If i enter an invalid number of seats ex: economy section has 8 seats. but if I enter a number greater than that it, the program doesn't go on to the else statement and print the error message.

Instead it just goes through the if statement and does the calculations with the invalid seat number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FlightProfit
{
        String location;

        int TOLEDO_FARE = 200;
        int HOUSTON_FARE = 300;
        int BOISE_FARE = 400;

        int economySeats;
        int businessSeats;
        int firstClassSeats;

        int economySales;
        int businessSales;
        int firstClassSales;
        //int totalSales = economySales + businessSales + firstClassSales;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        public int addEconomySeats()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of economy seats 1-8: ");
            economySeats = in.nextInt();

            if(economySeats > 0 || economySeats < 9)
            {
                return economySeats;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Only 8 seats available in economy.");
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public int addBusinessSeats()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of business seats sold: ");
            businessSeats = in.nextInt();

            if(businessSeats > 0 || economySeats < 7)
            {
                return businessSeats;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Only 6 seats available in business.");
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public int addFirstClassSeats()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of first class seats sold: ");
            firstClassSeats = in.nextInt();

            if(firstClassSeats > 0 || firstClassSeats < 5)
            {
                return firstClassSeats;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Only 4 seats available in first class.");
            }

            return 0;
        }



       public void getProfit(String loc)
       {
           location = loc;

           if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("toledo"))
           {
               economySales = economySeats * TOLEDO_FARE;
               businessSales = businessSeats * (2 * TOLEDO_FARE);
               firstClassSales = firstClassSeats * (4 * TOLEDO_FARE);
               System.out.println("Economy Sales: " + economySeats + " seats: " + economySales);
               System.out.println("Business Sales: " + businessSeats + " seats: " + businessSales);
               System.out.println("First Class Sales: " + firstClassSeats + " seats: " + firstClassSales);
               //System.out.println("Total Sales: " + totalSales);
           }
           else if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("houston"))
           {
               economySales = economySeats * HOUSTON_FARE;
               businessSales = businessSeats * (2 * HOUSTON_FARE);
               firstClassSales = firstClassSeats * (4 * HOUSTON_FARE);
               System.out.println("Economy Sales: " + economySeats + " seats: " + economySales);
               System.out.println("Business Sales: " + businessSeats + " seats: " + businessSales);
               System.out.println("First Class Sales: " + firstClassSeats + " seats: " + firstClassSales);
              // System.out.println("Total Sales: " + totalSales);
           }
           else
           {
               economySales = economySeats * BOISE_FARE;
               businessSales = businessSeats * (2 * BOISE_FARE);
               firstClassSales = firstClassSeats * (4 * BOISE_FARE);
               System.out.println("Economy Sales: " + economySeats + " seats: " + economySales);
               System.out.println("Business Sales: " + businessSeats + " seats: " + businessSales);
               System.out.println("First Class Sales: " + firstClassSeats + " seats: " + firstClassSales);
               //System.out.println("Total Sales: " + totalSales);
           }
       }
}
```

==MAIN==

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aviation 
{

    public Aviation()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int option;

       FlightCost newFlight = new FlightCost();
       FlightProfit flight = new FlightProfit();

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter new flight location: ");
       String location = in.next();

       do{
       String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                   + "\n1 (1) Get flight costs."
                   + "\n2 (2) Get flight profits."
                   + "\n3 (3) Enter names/meals."
                   + "\n4 (4) Exit.";

       System.out.println(menu);
       option = in.nextInt();

       }while (option < 0 || option > 4);

       switch(option)
       {
           case 1:
              newFlight.getCost(location);
              break;
           case 2:
              flight.addEconomySeats();
              flight.addBusinessSeats();
              flight.addFirstClassSeats();
              flight.getProfit(location);
              break;
           case 3:
               //newFlight.flyers();
               break;
           case 4:
               System.out.println("Exit");
               break;
           default:
               System.out.println("Error: must select menu option.");
       }      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (economySeats > 0 || economySeats < 9)`

This condition is always true (since any number is either positive or less than 9), so of course you don't reach the else clause.

You probably want the `&&` (and) operator :

`if (economySeats > 0 && economySeats < 9)`

And your other conditions have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (economySeats > 0 && economySeats < 9)
```

As  `economySeats` should be greater then 0 and smaller then 9. then only the condition will follow to the else statement.

when you use  `if (economySeats > 0 || economySeats < 9)`
it means that `economySeat` should be greater then 0 (so if you input value greater then 0 then this  condition will be true) so, that's why you are thinking that the if statement isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your number range check does not work as you intend to was already given. I'd howver like to hint that you could do range checks somewhat more elegant and less error-prone by using Guava's 'Range' type:

```
Range economySeatsRange = Range.atLeast(1).atMost(8);
//...
boolean inAllowedRange = economySeatsRange.apply(economySeats);
if(inAllowedRange)
    // between 1 and 8
else
    // signal error
```

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html